# Why is killing and eating certain animals allowed when we have enough supply of vegetarian food?

Tags: quran, animals, meat

- Why is killing and eating certain animals allowed when we have enough supply of vegetarian food?

I agree that in desert area absence of vegetation and agriculture makes eating livestocks a necessary item for survival. But today it can be totally avoided as and where circumstances permits.
Our Quran prohibits eating dead animals, blood and swine and other things which also have been proved by scientific evidence are detrimental to health.
It has also been proved that humans are herbivores according to human biology and eating of meat products in long term causes various ailment.

My additional questions are:

- Are animal created for the sole purpose of eating, unlike mankind and jinns, they don't have any purpose in life? (references needed)
- Are we not eating meat for the purpose of taste/luxury rather than necessity?
- Is it not possible that Quran allowed to eat halal meat (which does not have major impact on health) since vegetation where absent in desert areas of Arabian peninsula and middle east?

Comment: What would you do in Eid ul Adha..Qurbani a pumpkin? As well as for Qurbani during the specific times e.g. when a child is born...the eating of animal meat is important for the health of human beings. Therefore it cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

`Are animal created for the sole purpose of eating, unlike mankind and jinns they don't have any purpose in life ? (references needed)`

Yes, Allah created the animals for us as he explains in the Quran:

[image]

> And the grazing livestock He has created for you; in them is warmth and [numerous] benefits, and from them you eat. [16:5]

`Are we not eating Meat for the purpose of taste/luxury rather than necessity ? Is it not possible that Quran allowed to eat halal meat (which does not have major impact on health) since vegetation where absent in desert areas of Arabian peninsula and middle east ?`

Medically speaking, eating meat is necessary for a healthy human being. A [study](http://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/176565) showed that a whopping 92% of vegans are deficient in a critical B12 vitamin. There are many other negative effects for Vegan, it is hard to keep healthy as a vegan without additional vitamin supplements and medication.

All societies, including western eat meat for the healthy nutrients it contains, it is not something that only people without vegetation do.

Comment: You answered my points but i want to add vitamin B12 are available in fortified food and supplement. And I haven't ask for vegan diet but rather my question pertains to killing of animal.

Comment: They basically go hand in hand. Vegan = no animal killing/eating. I hope I did make it clear that you still can be vegan and health, like you said throughout food, supplements and medications.

Comment: @user12537 nice answer :-)